# Why does calling ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].callback('TOKEN'); on PayPal website throws undefined error?

Tags: javascript, paypal, recaptcha, 2captcha

I’m currently trying to bypass reCAPTCHA on https://www.paypal.com/cz/welcome/signup/#. I am using python with 2captcha API. I don’t have any problems with API, because I always recieve my token succesfully. My problem is that i can’t submit it to the site. There isn’t any submit button, so there needs to be some callback function. I have already asked on 2Captcha support and they said that in order to call that function I have to do : ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].es.l.callback("TOKEN"); and gave me a script to find the correct path. This works great on other sites with reCAPTCHA, but not on PayPal. Even when the reCaptcha code seems to be similar on all the sites.I’d be grateful for any solution and advice :-).

Thanks,

Adam Hendrych

Answer (score 1):

finally solved it. Just my extreme stupidity :-). Just need to switch the directory that you run the script in. If that makes sense. Look at the image included.

[directory change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBMaF.png)

Comment: The callback function path keeps changing every few days. So do you have a way to find the current path via script (powershell, phython, php ). Thanks

Comment: Hi, I do not remember what I exactly used for this, but I think that I have used script that you can find here [link](http://network.ubotstudio.com/forum/index.php/topic/22568-ask-find-callback-function-for-recaptcha-v2-invisible/.). Give it a try :-)